# Почему strlen неточно определяет количество символов?

Tags: c

```
char buffer[] = "<center>asdfsafasdfasdfasdfadfdfg4444444444444444444333333333333663333333333563453245gdfgaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa35234dkfgnskldjfgjsdfghsdfg 1</center>";

(char)strlen(buffer); // возвращает "-52"
```

Как такое вообще происходит?

Comment: Кстати, в случае выше вместо strlen(buffer) лучше использовать sizeof(buffer)-1.

Comment: Это правда. Но сейчас речь не об этом.

Comment: >Но сейчас речь не об этом.

 Но на вопрос уже ответили давно.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

char имеет диапазон значений от -127 до 128.
А у вас вроде 208 символов (если BBEdit правильно посчитал).
Попробуйте unsigned char или unsigned int.

Comment: Тут же массив чаров?..

Comment: Да. И что не так?

Comment: А, ступил, всё логично, вопрос коряво прочитал.

Answer (score 4):

А зачем вы приводите результат к char? Обычно char может хранить только числа в диапазоне [-128, 127]. Поэтому при приведении size_t (тип результата strlen) к char берется только самый младший байт. В вашем случае результат больше 127 поэтому из-за переполнения получается отрицательное число.

Answer (score 4):

прототип:

```
size_t strlen(const char *_Str)
```

Возвращает количество символов в строке - когда вы преобразуете в char, происходит уменьшение разрядности из за этого и происходит такая фигня.

Не надо преобразовывать в (char)

`printf("%d",strlen(buffer));`

Answer (score 2):

а еще нужно помнить о том, что русские буквы кодируются в utf8 (если ваши исходники в utf8) не одним байтом, а двумя

Comment: Не данный случай, но замечание правильное.

Comment: хорошо бы еще и терминирующий '\0' в строке разглядеть

Comment: Терминирующий ноль strlen игнорирует

Comment: Отнюдь не игнорирует, а прекращает счититать char-ы.

Comment: А я вот  этого не знал. Ну и дурак же я.

Comment: Никто не может знать всего :)

Comment: Всей водки не выпьешь, всех женщин не... Но стремиться надо.